# What does "Despite being born in India, Chinese-origin people stateless" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, indian-english, headlinese

This is a headline in today's newspaper:

> Despite being born in India, Chinese-origin people stateless

What does this mean, especially Despite and Chinese-Origin?

Comment: "Chinese-origin people stateless" has no verb, so this is not a complete sentence. Can't tell what you are trying to say.

Comment: Actually this is a headline in todays news paper I saw that sentence and didn't understand that's why I posted here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of "despite" used here means the same as "even though".

"Chinese-origin" just means ethnic Chinese (persons whose ancestors were from China), even though actually born in India.

So it is saying that persons of Chinese ethnicity, who are born in India, are stateless (meaning they are not accepted same as native Indians).

"Despite being born in India" indicates that being born in India does not matter nor change their situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means the nationality of chinese people who are born in india is not accepted as india anymore.